# Editing .plist file

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, jailbreak

I'm developing an app for jailbroken phones. I'm new to Obj-c. I want to:

1. Read a plist file in /var/mobile/Library/Preferences [specifically com.apple.assistant.plist] (Jailbroken, remember?)
2. Change the string for the key, "Hostname".
3. Save the plist file.

Then I plan to throw the code in a IBAction and link it to a button in IB.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Can you post the code for it?

Comment: What have you tried? Does that include [reading the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're mainly wondering about how to read/write the plist.  Here's an example of doing that:

```
NSString* filename = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.assistant.plist";
NSMutableDictionary* prefs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filename];
NSString* hostnamePref = (NSString*)[prefs valueForKey: @"Hostname"];
NSLog(@"current hostname is %@", hostnamePref);

[prefs setValue: @"Some New Value Here" forKey: @"Hostname"];

[prefs writeToFile: filename atomically: YES];
[prefs release];  // not needed if you use Automatic Reference Counting in your project
```

**Edit:** If your dictionary (plist) is actually a dictionary of dictionaries, you might use something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* prefs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filename];
NSString* nestedKeyname = @"124-37HGSH-CF12-67TY";
NSMutableDictionary* nestedPrefs = (NSMutableDictionary*)[prefs valueForKey: nestedKeyname];
NSString* hostnamePref = (NSString*)[nestedPrefs valueForKey: @"Hostname"];
NSLog(@"current hostname is %@", hostnamePref);

[nestedPrefs setValue: @"Some New Value Here" forKey: @"Hostname"];
[prefs setValue: nestedPrefs forKey: nestedKeyname];
```

The above code should work for any path that user **mobile** has permission to read and write.

Comment: It works, well sort of. I had to change dict to prefs. But it creates the key hostname not edits it. Then I found out that it's in a dictionary inside of the dictionary. The inside dictionary is called 124-37HGSH-CF12-67TY. How can I adapt your code to do this?

Comment: @user1405727, sorry about the typo (fixed in edit).  I'm not at my Mac now, so the additional code I added is also not compiler-tested yet.  I'll check it when I get back home.  But, the basic idea should show you how to drill into nested dictionaries.  Also, if you're unclear about the contents of your plist file, you can install `plutil` from Cydia, or use ssh and copy the plist file back to your Mac, and open it with Mac's Property List Editor.  that will clarify the plist structure before you waste too much time trying to discover the contents with code. good luck.

Comment: @user1405727, also it could help if you added a little more detail about the contents of the plist file to your question above.  That file doesn't exist on everyone's device, and developers who aren't jailbroken won't be able to inspect the filesystem as easily ... but your basic question is about reading and saving plists, which isn't only an issue for jailbreak development.  Just trying to help you get the best answers to your question.